# Locating markers on the google map

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

Hello friends i am uploading my code from last few days on the stackoverflow but somwhow i am not getting the thing which i want. Noe once again i am trying this please try to help me out and solve my proplems. Firstly see the code.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

welcomeViewController.h

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface welcomemapViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *txt;
@end
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

welcomeViewController.m

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
#import "welcomemapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kLatestSearchURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=Delhi&sensor=true&key=Your API key"]

@interface welcomemapViewController ()
@end


@implementation welcomemapViewController
{
    GMSMapView *gmap;
}

@synthesize txt;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     GMSCameraPosition *cam = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:30.7343000 longitude:76.7933000 zoom:12];
     gmap = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480) camera:cam];
     gmap.myLocationEnabled = YES;
     gmap.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
     gmap.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
     gmap.settings.zoomGestures = YES;
     gmap.settings.tiltGestures = NO;
     gmap.settings.rotateGestures = YES;
     [self.view addSubview:gmap];

     GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.751288, 76.780899);
     marker.title = @"Sector -16";
     marker.snippet = @"Chandigarh";
     marker.map = gmap;

     UIButton *button    = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     button.frame        = CGRectMake(200, 65, 100, 40);
     [button setTitle:@"SEARCH" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(search:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:button];

     CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(10, 68, 200, 30);
     txt =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame2];
     txt.placeholder = @"Search";
     txt.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
     [txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

     [self.view addSubview:txt];

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=30.7343000,76.7933000&radius=500&types=food&name&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCGeIN7gCxU8baq3e5eL0DU3_JHeWyKzic"];
    //Formulate the string as URL object.
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSString *data1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"Response data: %@", data1);
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    NSArray* responseResults = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    NSLog(@"Locations are %@", responseResults);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

now in "**NSLog(@"Locations are %@", responseResults);**" i am getting my values, i simply want to add these values onto the map in the form of pointers with details.
 So kindly help me how it should be done. (**And kindly help me with the help of codes**)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using MKPointAnnotation and then add this MKPointAnnotation in you mapview

CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

```
annotationCoord.latitude = @"your Latitude to point on map";
annotationCoord.longitude =  @"your Longitude to point on map";;
```

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

```
annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
annotationPoint.title = @"your title";
annotationPoint.subtitle = @"your subtitle";
```

[YourmapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

Comment: before doing this we have to extract the data for the array "**NSArray* responseResults = [json objectForKey:@"results"];** ", how can we do that??

Comment: congrats ! 450+ for ,,,,,, :)